# Unknown column 'list' in 'field list' php mysql multiple selections

Tags: php, mysql

I'm not sure what I a missing here... Any pointers would be greatly appreciated. keep getting Unknown column 'list' in 'field list' for some reason. I'm not sure what I am missing exactly.

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['list'])) {
  $_POST['list'] = implode(',', $_POST['list']);
} 
if ((isset($_POST["MM_insert"])) && ($_POST["MM_insert"] == "create_list")) {
   $insertSQL = sprintf("INSERT INTO listp (one) Values (%s)"),  
     GetSQLValueString($_POST['company_category'], "text"));
?>

<select name="list[]" size="12" multiple="multiple" id="list">

<?php

do {  

?>
  <option value="<?php echo $row_huff_list['id'] ?>">
    <?php 
    echo $row_huff_list['list']
    ?>
  </option>

<?php
  } while ($row_huff_list = mysql_fetch_assoc($huff_list));

  $rows = mysql_num_rows($huff_list);
  if($rows > 0) {
    mysql_data_seek($huff_list, 0);
    $row_huff_list = mysql_fetch_assoc($huff_list);
  }
?>
</select>
```

Comment: your code have got misstake syntax. **`sprintf("INSERT INTO`** i dont know where is end of this command

Comment: One thing I found, `$insertSQL = sprintf("INSERT INTO listp (one) Values (%s)",` should probably be this `$insertSQL = sprintf("INSERT INTO listp (one) Values (%s)"),` you missed the closing **)**. If that fixed it, let me know if I can make it as an answer.

Comment: It did have all that. I just didn't copy it correctly to the stackoverflow website. Actually I was also missing a bigger chunk. Sorry. coding stuff for the last 18 hours here. :) but to answer your question its still not working correctly.

Comment: Get some sleep. Coding, yet alone working with a clear head, always prevails in solving problems as such; believe me, I know. Sorry I couldn't be of more help. Take it easy ;-)

Comment: That SQL error says you have no *list* column. BTW id attribute should have no brackets []

Comment: Thank you for everyone elses support.. Ok I took out the bracket along the id. What would cause the no list? maybe I am missing something else here.

Answer (score 0):

Its super simple: `$row_huff_list` is not defined when the program enter the loop for the first time, only at the end of the first loop, the `$row_huff_list` is assigned some value, for second time its ok already, just change `do-while` loop to `while` loop, like this:

```
 while ($row_huff_list = mysql_fetch_assoc($huff_list)) {
    ?>
    <option value="<?php echo $row_huff_list['id'] ?>">
        <?php 
        echo $row_huff_list['list']
        ?>
    </option>
    <?php
}
```

Comment: try `var_dump($row_huff_list)` before echoing `$row_huff_list['list']`